# PHP switch and class property issue

Tags: php

I am trying to set the property and use it on another function.

I have

```
while($texts->employees()){
      $employee = $employees->get();

      switch($employee->getInfoType()){

        case 'email':
            $this->buildemail($employee);
          break;
        case 'Name':
            $this->buildName($employee);
          break;
        case 'Numbers':
            $this->buildNumbers($employee);
          break;
     }

function buildEmail($employee){
    $this->email=$employee->getEmail();  //get the email.
}

function buildName($employee){
    $this->Name=$this->getName(); //get the name
    $this->employeeInfo=$this->email.$this->name;   //combine the email and numbers.

    //$this->email is '' becasue it's only defined in buildEmail(). 
}

function buildNumbers($employee){
     $this->numbers=$this->getNumbers();
}
```

I can't seem to get `$this->email` in buildName method because `this->email` is defined in `buildemail` method. 
I need to use switch because there are so much codes in each methods. Are there anyways to do this?

Comment: You need your `switch` to call `$this->buildEmail()` before it calls `$this->buildName()`.

Comment: All these methods are in the same class? You didn't include the class 'wrapper' in your code sample, which may make your question confusing

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call `$employee->getEmail()` in your `buildName` method instead of relying on it being in `$email`?

Also:

```
    case 'Name':
        $this->buildName($employee);
    case 'Numbers':
        $this->buildNumbers($employee);
      break;
```

`buildName` and `buildNumbers` will both run if `$employee->getInfoType()` returns "Name." you're missing a `break;` between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do like:

```
function buildName($employee){
    $this->Name=$this->getName(); //get the name

    if(null == $this->email)
        $this->buildEmail($employee);

    $this->employeeInfo= $this->email.$this->name;   //combine the email and numbers.

    //$this->email is '' becasue it's only defined in buildEmail(). 
}
```

I assume that each employee has to have an email, is that correct?